# System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException : System.AccessViolationException

Tags: php, .net, web-services

I work with a webservice used simultaneously by different users and sometimes we encounter the following error:

```
SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Le serveur n'a pas pu traiter la demande. ---> System.AccessViolationException: Tentative de lecture ou d'écriture de mémoire protégée.
```

This error occurs randomly and the only way to unblock the situation is to recycle the application pool.

I exploit the webservice in php and the webservice is written in .NET.

Does anyone have any idea where this problem may come from?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by ' the webservice in php and the webservice is written in .NET.'?

Comment: The call of the webservice is done in a web application written in php (SoapClient).

The third-party application that provides the webservice is written in .NET.